# android studio not reflecting changes to app

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout, android-linearlayout, android-cardview

AS has started deploying old versions of app through adp, although in IDE layouts are update.
Android Studio Version "4.4.2"
Things i have tried

1. Rebuilding Project
2. Reinstalling app
3. Invalidating caches and restart
4. Restarting PC/Electricity Meter
5. Restarting transformer from Local Grid

Below is comparison
[image]

I have included my whole layout file because i did not want to miss anything.
Note: I have removed namespaces and margins from the layout to reduce code

```
<androidx.appcompat.widget.LinearLayoutCompat
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/gradientLightOrange">
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/bg_shadeofgrey"
        android:orientation="vertical">
<LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">
<TextView
                style="@style/viewParent.headerText"
                android:layout_margin="20dp"
                android:text="@string/appHeaderText" />
<TextView
                style="@style/viewParent.headerText.contentText"
                android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="-20dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
                android:text="Never trust anyone who has not brought a book with them."
                tools:ignore="HardcodedText" />
</LinearLayout>
<LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="60dp"
            android:orientation="vertical">
<LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal">
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="100dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1">
<ImageView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:layout_margin="30dp"
                        android:gravity="center"

                        android:src="@drawable/ic_play"
                        android:textAllCaps="false"
                        android:textColor="@color/black"
                        android:textStyle="bold" />
</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1">
<ImageView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:layout_margin="30dp"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:src="@drawable/ic_grid"
                        android:textAllCaps="false"
                        android:textColor="@color/black"
                        android:textStyle="bold" />
</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
</LinearLayout>
<LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal">
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="100dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1">
<ImageView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"

                        android:layout_margin="30dp"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:src="@drawable/ic_follow"
                        android:textAllCaps="false"
                        android:textColor="@color/black"
                        android:textStyle="bold" />
</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="100dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1">
<ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/sound_text_view"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:layout_margin="30dp"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:textAllCaps="false"
                        android:textColor="@color/black"
                        android:textStyle="bold" />
</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
</LinearLayout>
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="60dp">
<ImageView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_margin="10dp"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:src="@drawable/settings"
                    android:textAllCaps="false"
                    android:textColor="@color/black"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />
</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
</LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
</androidx.appcompat.widget.LinearLayoutCompat>
```

Comment: So your changes are shown in Android Studio, but not when you debug your app on your smartphone? Are you sure you are showing the right layout in your activity/fragment or even showing the right activity?

Comment: @SlothCoding Yes exactly

Comment: Can you share your Activity code where this View is set as contentView?

Comment: you can use Constraint layout as root